# React-native/Libraries/Components/ScrollResponder could not be found

Tags: reactjs, react-native

i actualize the node_module by doing nom install, then the doesn't work again and I became this error: Unable to resolve module react-native/Libraries/Components/ScrollResponder from /Users/project/node_modules/deprecated-react-native-listview/index.js: react-native/Libraries/Components/ScrollResponder could not be found within the project or in these directories:
node_modules
../node_modules.

in Package.json I have this version of react-native
"react": "^17.0.2",
"react-native": "^0.66.0",
...
Please help me I am a beginner, thanks a lot

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I take a look at react-native source code and I realized that `ScrollResponder` component was removed when react-native v0.65. Your react-native version is 0.66.0 therefore get this error.

Check the diff react-native v0.64 with v0.65 here: https://github.com/facebook/react-native/compare/0.64-stable...0.65-stable

You can consider downgrading your react-native version or use an alternative component instead of `deprecated-react-native-listview`.

Answer (score 4):

I had this problem with version 0.0.6 of [deprecated-react-native-listview](https://www.npmjs.com/package/deprecated-react-native-listview)  but version 0.0.7 has a fix for this.